# glBlitFramebuffer vs GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT

Tags: opengl

I have a custom framebuffer which has a depth and stencil attachment:

```
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId, 0);
```

Does the following operation blit depth and stencil or only depth ?

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, fboId);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, w, h, 0, 0, w, h, GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);
```

What will happen when in the above operation I replace `GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT` with `GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `glBlitFramebuffer` with `GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT`, only the depth buffer is copied and if you call it with `GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT` only the stencil buffer is copied. If you want to copy both buffers at once you have to set both bits:

```cpp
glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, w, h, 0, 0, w, h,
    GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);
```